# How to integrate CCavenue in laravel 10

Tags: payment-gateway, laravel-10, ccavenue

I am currently working on integrating CCAvenue payment gateway into my Laravel 10 project. In Laravel 8, I successfully used the indipay package for this purpose. However, it seems that `indipay` is not supported in Laravel 9 and 10. I have researched alternatives and haven't found a Laravel-compatible CCAvenue package. what is best approach to integrate CCAvenue with Laravel 10, considering the lack of support for `indipay`.